# If não está sendo executado

Tags: javascript, if, null, else

Me deparei com um problema, quando vou executar esse código no navegador, o if é simplesmente ignorado, não consigo achar a resposta pra isso, já tentei algumas coisas com o meu conhecimento atual mas não obtive êxito. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pratica</title> </head>

<body>
    <h1>Você é brasileiro?</h1>
    Digite um país <input class="text" name="txtv" id="txtv">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="verificar()">

    <div id="res">

    </div>

    <script>

        function verificar() {
            let txtv = document.getElementById('#txtv');
            let res = document.querySelector('#res');

            if (txtv == 'Brasil') {
                res.innerHTML = 'Você é brasileiro'
            } else {  
            res.innerHTML = 'Você é estrangeiro'
            }
        }

    </script> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Só uma curiosidade, isso é de algum curso? É porque já deve ser a milésima vez que aparece essa pergunta por aqui - [basta pesquisar](/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+brasileiro+if) e vai encontrar várias parecidas (sem contar as que foram apagadas). Enfim, é só pra reforçar o que a [Central de Ajuda](/help/on-topic) diz: "_[dê uma olhada](/search) para ver se sua pergunta foi feita anteriormente_". Uma simples busca já teria dado a resposta, e evitaria poluir o site com mais uma pergunta igual...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Dentro da função quando vc declara a variavel txtv, vc seleciona ela por ID. E o erro é pq vc colocou #, quando é selecionado por Id nao é necessario.

Segue codigo:

```js
function verificar() {
    let txtv = document.getElementById('txtv'); // Remova o '#' aqui
    let res = document.querySelector('#res');

    if (txtv.value.toLowerCase() === 'brasil') {
        res.innerHTML = 'Você é brasileiro';
    } else {  
        res.innerHTML = 'Você é estrangeiro';
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Cauã! Caraca! Eu to em parafuso nisso desde às 23h30 kkkkkkk Obrigado mesmo! Amanhã irei ler as documentações de .value e de .toLowerCase, não fazia ideia que eu deveria coloca-las no código!

Comment: Tmjj. Essas coisinhas q tiram a cabeça do lugar kkk.
Coloquei os métodos .value e .toLowerCase para que considere a escrita em letras minúsculas.